# AFNetworking Post domain: @"NSCocoaErrorDomain" - code: 3840

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json

I am trying to implement a POST on a WS that manages its serialization with JArray.Parse (string) for which I have to send a serialized string. But at the time of sending it returns me this error:

> error NSError * domain: @"NSCocoaErrorDomain" - code: 3840
>   0x00007fd520e469f0 Unexpected character encountered while parsing
>   value: =. Path '', line 0, position 0.'
>
> Cache-Control: private Transfer-Encoding: chunked Allow: POST
>   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
>   X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Date: Fri, 27 Nov
>   2015 04:44:18 GMT

I leave my code:

```
 NSMutableDictionary *tmp = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: .......nil];
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:tmp options:0 error:&error];
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"JSON Output: %@", jsonString);
    AFSecurityPolicy *policy = [[AFSecurityPolicy alloc] init];
    [policy setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES];
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *operationManager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [operationManager setSecurityPolicy:policy];
    [operationManager POST:@"URLPOST" parameters:jsonData success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", [responseObject description]);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", operation.responseString);
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", operation.responseData);
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", operation.responseObject);
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", operation.responseSerializer);
        NSLog(@"JSON Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

    }];
```

As you can see I am transforming an `NSMutableDictionary` to `NSData` and then to an `NSString` which I returns: {}, {}. E tested with `manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];` and and not succeeded. Also I was wondering how that same serialized string can be so; [{},{}]

EDIT

After several hours with attempts failed with AFNetworking started to try other things aside from the code already existing which could fix the error leave the part of the code in case anyone else has the same problem :

```
NSMutableDictionary *tmp = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: ...nil];
NSArray *tmpArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:tmp];
NSData *JsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:tmpArray options:0 error:NULL];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[JsonData length]];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"URL"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"Close" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Connection"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"text/plain" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:JsonData];
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"response - %@",responseString);
```

Comment: can you format your code

Comment: Don't you need a single top-level root object in JSON?

Comment: Already solve the problem let my code above, but I can not give you the format to the code can help me on that? Best regards.